# Puntos más allá de zlim en filled.contour

Tags: r

Tengo una inquietud generando la siguiente gráfica, con la función `filled.contour;` sólo me interesa pintar en detalle los gradientes para el rango entre 290 y 295, pero si uso `zlim`, entonces en la gráfica (que es de temperaturas), me quedan unos espacios en blanco.

¿Alguien sabe si puedo implementar algo que me permita categorizar los valores extremos de la gráfica, es decir, si son valores `< 290` que queden con el color más bajo de la barra y si son `> 295`, que queden con el más alto? Esto para que no me queden espacios en blanco en la gráfica de contorno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

@vagora, sería bueno que siempre adjuntes el código para analizar lo que estás haciendo. Me costo un poco darme cuenta cual era tu requerimiento y al no tener un ejemplo tuve que armar uno. La solución no pasa por usar `zlim`, en realidad lo que conviene hacer es igualar los valores superiores a los limites que queres imponer. Veamos un ejemplo:

```
matriz <- structure(runif(400, 285, 300), 
                 .Dim = c(10L, 40L)
)
matriz=t(apply(matriz,1,sort))
row.names(matriz) <- as.character.Date(seq(ISOdate(2011,8,1), by = "day", length.out = 10))
colnames(matriz) <- c(seq(1:40))
dates <- as.Date(dimnames(matriz)[[1]], "%Y-%m-%d")
depths <- as.numeric(dimnames(matriz)[[2]])
filled.contour(x=dates,
               y=depths,
               z=matriz, 
               xlab="Date", 
               ylab="Depth",
               col = rev(colorRampPalette(c('darkred','red','blue','lightblue'))(25))
)
```

Este ejemplo genera el siguiente gráfico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si aplicamos `zlim` al gráfico va a ocurrir lo que mostrabas

```
filled.contour(x=dates,
               y=depths,
               z=matriz, 
               xlab="Date", 
               ylab="Depth",
               col = rev(colorRampPalette(c('darkred','red','blue','lightblue'))(25)),
               zlim=c(290,295)
)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que sí podemos hacer es igualar los valores inferiores y superiores de la matriz a los límites

```
matriz[matriz < 290] <- 290
matriz[matriz > 295] <- 295
```

Y entonces llegamos a quitar las superficies blancas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]